# prevent mounted iso opening at startup

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have saved some of my children's educational DVDs on my wife's laptop as .iso files and put shortcuts to them on the desktop. When the icons are double-clicked Daemon Tools Lite mounts them and autoplay starts them up.

My problem is that when the children exit the games the .iso file is still mounted, so on startup my wife is greeted by a screaming introduction to whatever fun stealth-learning adventure my kids previously chose.

Can anyone suggest how to either

- automatically unmount the iso after the program exits, or
- disable autoplay *on startup* but not otherwise..

Free solutions preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "startup" you mean rebooting the PC, there's an option in the DAEMON Tools Lite settings menu named "Automount" that will mount the latest used ISO files at system start, so disabling this would help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Daemon Tools has a command-line switch](http://daemon-help.com/en/windows_integration_lite/command_line_parameters.html) to dismount all drives, example:

> DTLite.exe -unmount_all

Perhaps stick this in a batch file and use the Task Scheduler to run it at "Log on" or "Workstation Unlock".